# Firebase Database Rest Api: EndAt() Returns Duplicate Result When multiple nodes with same value

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I hope you have a good day

I'm using the Firebase Database Rest API to fetch the first top 10 posts ordered by (Views)
and When I fetch the first 10 posts, there is no problem Like This:

https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10

```
{
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "Im 11",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 11
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn" : {
    "Text" : "Im 11 Two",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 11
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhds2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 13
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhewtpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 14
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtdxpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 15
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtp11En" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 16
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01sdifhtpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 17
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPOd01ifh2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Title" : "some title",
    "Views" : 18
  },
  "3342323231" : {
    "Text" : "d",
    "Title" : 24,
    "Views" : 19
  },
  "444444444444" : {
    "Text" : "dd",
    "Title" : "xzx",
    "Views" : 20
  }
}
```

And when I sort first 10 elements in order of highest **Views** The last id will be **-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn** And when I fetch another 11 elements starting from the **LastId** and **LastValue** it will return the result of a duplicate data because there are two elements with the same value of (**Views**) but it is supposed to not do that because I have passed the **LastValue** as well as the **LastId** Like this:

https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11&endAt=11,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn%22

I expected it would return a duplicate result which is the last element only **-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn** I can remove it easily but why does it return other elements that were shown in the first 10 ?

**I tried not to make any item contain a duplicate value and the results are correct and there are no duplicate posts** So what is the solution to this problem?

Sorry for the long post, and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the final page of results with https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10, the first two nodes in the results are:

```
"-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn" : {
  "Text" : "Im 11",
  "Views" : 11
},
"-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn" : {
  "Text" : "Im 11 Two",
  "Views" : 11
},
```

In the call in your question you're passing in the `-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn` key, which is the **second** key from the results you already had. So that's then also where Firebase starts/ends the slice of data it returns.

If you want only one overlapping item, use key `-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn`: https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11&endAt=11,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn%22

This will then give you these results:

```
{
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01dxifhtpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 1
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 2
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfh2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 3
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfhtpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 4
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idxfh2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "must 5",
    "Views" : 6
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 5
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifdshtpEn" : {
    "Text" : "must 7",
    "Views" : 7
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh21tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 8
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2dstpEn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 9
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEdsn" : {
    "Text" : "some text",
    "Views" : 10
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn" : {
    "Text" : "Im 11",
    "Views" : 11
  }
}
```

I recommend using more readable and recognizable keys in a repro such as this, as it's quite easy to overlook the difference in those two keys in the first snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm saving the last id from the first 10 elements, how will I know if I have to choose the correct last id,Because in the normal situation, when there is no similar value, the results will be correct, and if I change the syntax of the keys will it solve this problem

Comment: After ordering on the property value, the nodes are ordered on key. So the first node is the one with the lowest `Views` value and the "lowest" key.

Comment: I understood it well, because before I used to store the last id by uisng `Last().Key()` but The correct way is `First().Key`, now everything is working correctly, thank you for helping me with a lot of previous questions, and now also, you are a wonderful person, I wish you a good day 